# Refresh portion of the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, jquery-dialog

I have a page that contains 3 divisions such as General, Attendee Information and Customized Questions (Partial view). The Customized questions will display a list of questions (textbox) along with the answer(dropdownlist) , which contains an edit button to modify the answer field in the dropdownlist. Now, when the edit button was clicked, a pop-up window will appear to modify the answer field, once the user clicked the save button the modified answer should reflects in the dropdownlist. I already created a partial view for Customized Questions but still the answer value didn't reflect the changes in the dropdownlist. Any sample codes or ideas?

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
       public ActionResult UpdateAnswers(string answers, string question, string controlid, int eventid)
       {
           var replacetext=string.Empty;
           if (answers.Length>0) 
             replacetext = answers.Replace("\n", ",");
           _service.UpdateAnswers(eventid, replacetext, controlid);
           var eventdetails = _service.GeteventByID(eventid);
           return PartialView( "CustomizedQuestions", eventdetails);
       }
```

**Partial View**

```
@using EM.Website.Helpers
@model EM.Model.tbl_SBAem_Event
@{
    var dropdownList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> {new KeyValuePair<int, string>(0, "Required"), new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "Optional"), new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "Hidden")};
    var selectList = new SelectList(dropdownList, "key", "value", 0);
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <table class="table-customized-question">
                <tr>
                    <th class="td-customized-question-row"></th>
                    <th class="td-customized-question-row">Question Label</th>
                    <th class="td-customized-question-row">Display Mode</th>
                    <th class="td-customized-question-row">Answer Field</th>
                    <th class="td-customized-question-row">Edit Choices</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td-customized-question-firstrow">#1</td>
                    <td class="td-customized-question-row">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EM_opt1Name)</td>
                    <td class="td-customized-question-row">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EM_reqOpt1, selectList)</td>
                    <td class="td-customized-question-row">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EM_opt1Values, @Html.SplitText(Model.EM_opt1Values, ','), new { @class = "dropdownlist-width" })</td>
                    <td>@Html.ActionImage("CustomizedQuestion", new { eventID = Model.EventMngID, question = Model.EM_opt1Name }, "~/Content/Images/edit.jpg", "Edit", new { @class = "editButton", title = Model.EM_opt1Name, answers = Model.EM_opt1Values, id = "EM_opt1Values", eventID = Model.EventMngID })</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td-customized-question-firstrow">#2</td>
                    <td class="td-customized-question-row">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EM_opt2Name)</td>
                    <td class="td-customized-question-row">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EM_reqOpt2, selectList)</td>

                    <td>@Html.ActionImage("CustomizedQuestion", new { eventID = Model.EventMngID, question = Model.EM_opt2Name }, "~/Content/Images/edit.jpg", "Edit", new { @class = "editButton", title = Model.EM_opt2Name, answers = Model.EM_opt2Values, id = "EM_opt2Values", eventID = Model.EventMngID })</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td-customized-question-firstrow">#3</td>
                    <td class="td-customized-question-row">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EM_opt3Name)</td>
                    <td class="td-customized-question-row">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EM_reqOpt3, selectList)</td>
                    <td class="td-customized-question-row">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EM_opt3Values, @Html.SplitText(Model.EM_opt3Values, ','), new { @class = "dropdownlist-width" })</td>
                    <td>@Html.ActionImage("CustomizedQuestion", new { eventID = Model.EventMngID, question = Model.EM_opt3Name }, "~/Content/Images/edit.jpg", "Edit", new { @class = "editButton", title = Model.EM_opt3Name, answers = Model.EM_opt3Values, id = "EM_opt3Values", eventID = Model.EventMngID })</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td-customized-question-firstrow">#4</td>
                    <td class="td-customized-question-row">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EM_opt4Name)</td>
                    <td class="td-customized-question-row">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EM_reqOpt4, selectList)</td>
                    <td class="td-customized-question-row">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EM_opt4Values, @Html.SplitText(Model.EM_opt4Values, ','), new { @class = "dropdownlist-width" })</td>
                    <td>@Html.ActionImage("CustomizedQuestion", new { eventID = Model.EventMngID, question = Model.EM_opt4Name }, "~/Content/Images/edit.jpg", "Edit", new { @class = "editButton", title = Model.EM_opt4Name, answers = Model.EM_opt4Values, id = "EM_opt4Values", eventID = Model.EventMngID })</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td-customized-question-firstrow">#5</td>
                    <td class="td-customized-question-row">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EM_opt5Name)</td>
                    <td class="td-customized-question-row">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EM_reqOpt5, selectList)</td>
                    <td class="td-customized-question-row">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EM_opt5Values, @Html.SplitText(Model.EM_opt5Values, ','), new { @class = "dropdownlist-width" })</td>
                    <td>@Html.ActionImage("CustomizedQuestion", new { eventID = Model.EventMngID, question = Model.EM_opt5Name }, "~/Content/Images/edit.jpg", "Edit", new { @class = "editButton", title = Model.EM_opt5Name, answers = Model.EM_opt5Values, id = "EM_opt5Values", eventID = Model.EventMngID })</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td-customized-question-firstrow">#6</td>
                    <td class="td-customized-question-row">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EM_opt6Name)</td>
                    <td class="td-customized-question-row">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EM_reqOpt6, selectList)</td>
                    <td class="td-customized-question-row">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EM_opt6Values, @Html.SplitText(Model.EM_opt6Values, ','), new { @class = "dropdownlist-width" })</td>
                    <td>@Html.ActionImage("CustomizedQuestion", new { eventID = Model.EventMngID, question = Model.EM_opt6Name }, "~/Content/Images/edit.jpg", "Edit", new { @class = "editButton", title = Model.EM_opt6Name, answers = Model.EM_opt6Values, id = "EM_opt6Values", eventID = Model.EventMngID })</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

}
```

**Jquery-Ajax**

```
$(".editButton").live("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $title = $(this).attr("title");
                var $answers = $(this).attr("answers");
                var $controlid = $(this).attr("id");
                var $eventId = $(this).attr("eventID");
                dropdownlist($controlid, $title, $answers, $eventId);
            });

 function dropdownlist(controlid, title, answer, eventid) {
            var $answersreplaced = answer.replace(/\,/g, "&nbsp;\r");
            var $deleteDialog = $('<div><textarea id="answerlist"  rows="10" cols="50">' + $answersreplaced + '</textarea><div><div style="font-size:9px">(To change back to an open answer field, delete all choices above and save)</div>');
            $deleteDialog.dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 280,
                width: 350,
                title: title + " - Edit Choices",
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Save": function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateAnswers")',
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'html',
                            context: $(this),
                            data: {
                                answers: $("#answerlist").val(),
                                question: title,
                                controlid: controlid,
                                eventid: eventid
                            },
                            success: function (result) {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                                alert(result);
                                $("#"+controlid+"").html(data); 
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                //xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError
                                alert('there was a problem saving the new answers, please try again');
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

> Do my approach is correct?

Yes, your approach is correct. You could for example use [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) to implement the popup and editing part. The idea is to use AJAX in order to avoid refreshing the whole page but only the portion you are interested in. So the partial that will be shown in the modal dialog will contain a form that will be submitted to a controller action using AJAX and the server will return the partial view with the new information about the questions.

Comment: ok but how can I use the entity in partial view the same with the view? do the partial view can get automatically the entity the same with the view?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You could pass any view model to the partial view from the controller action.

Comment: Hi Darin- please see the updated details about the problem raised. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must use

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("action", "controller")',

            data: "{... parameterd}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                      .. $("#yourDivID").html(data);
            }
        });
```

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("action", "controller", ajaxOptions)) , not

@using (Html.BeginForm())

Comment: thank you very much, still i need the jquery-ajax code?it seems that the action and controller is calling in the partial view

Comment: yes. put your ajax code into a function and set it on "OnSuccess" option like this:     AjaxOptions ajaxOptions = new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "Post",
        UpdateTargetId = "yourDiv",
        OnSuccess = "yourFunction"
    };

Comment: here is an example in details http://geekswithblogs.net/blachniet/archive/2011/08/03/updating-partial-views-with-unobtrusive-ajax-in-mvc-3.aspx

Comment: well, i am confused now, i will update the details first and paste all the codes

Comment: Hi Cornel - I've updated already the details, I put the complete codes. As you can see, the edit button has a javascript function that retrieves the values from the attributes and calls the dropdownlist function to shows a pop-up window using ajax jquery technologies. how can i change it according to your suggestion?